# How do I extract numbers from a dataframe column which follows a recurring pattern using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataframe which has a column that follows a pattern as shown in the image as [Column Marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa9Wo.png)

I need to create two separate columns each containing ENG and HIN marks separately.

I am aware I need to use .extract and enter the pattern to extract the marks but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am using pandas.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The downvotes are happening because you posted a requirements-only question showing zero effort.  For best results here next time, please include your code and point out where you are stuck.

Comment: will do. I am new here

Comment: `df["ENG"] = df["Marks"].str.extract(r'ENG-(\d+)')` ... and so on for the `HIN` column.  The answer you accepted is way more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```py
i = 0
engMarks = []
hinMarks = []
for i in range(len(studentsDF)):
    marksString = studentsDF['Marks'][i]
    stringed = []
    for s in marksString:
        stringed.append(s)
    engMarks.append(int(stringed[4] + stringed[5]))
    hinMarks.append(int(stringed[15] + stringed[16]))
    
studentsDF['ENG Score'] = engMarks
studentsDF['HIN Score'] = hinMarks

studentsDF
```

Here is the code in Jupyter Notebook (so you can see the output):

[image: The code from above in a Jupyter Notebook cell with output.]

Essentially what I'm doing is getting the string of each student's marks, itemizing each character into an array, and getting the characters that correspond with the grade you're looking for. Then, I'm converting those to integers, appending them to new arrays containing all the scores for each respective class, and then adding those as new columns to the original `studentsDF` DataFrame.

Comment: Nice. Your code does work, and it works on the assumption that the pattern remains strictly constant, that is, the position of the characters remains the same.